# Get bridge name associated to docker Network

Tags: networking, docker, docker-network

i am creating a docker network using "docker network create --d bridge mynet". I want to get the bridge name that is associated to this docker network.

I know i can use the "-o" to provide bridge name. ex :"docker network create --d bridge -o com.docker.network.bridge.name=mybridge mynet". This method will work with normal bridge driver but in my case, I am using an ovs driver hence i am starting the network as "docker network create --d ovs mynet". If i use the "-o" in case of ovs driver it does not work.

please suggest me a way to get the bridge name associated to a network. The new bridge which is being created when i create the network,the bridge which has been created with it has a random name and i can see it using "ifconfig" command.

Answer (score 12):

Bridge name is not part of `docker network inspect` output, but it's always `br-<first 12 characters of network id>` (unless explicitly specified when creating the network with `-o com.docker.network.bridge.name=<bridge name>`).

```
network_id=$(docker network inspect -f {{.Id}} <network name>)
bridge_name="br-${network_id:0:12}"
```

Another option is to rely on the fact that the bridge serves as network's default gateway and therefore its IP address and  network's gateway address are the same.

```
network_gateway=$(docker inspect \
    -f '{{range .IPAM.Config}}{{.Gateway}}{{end}}' <network name>)
bridge_name=$(ifconfig | grep -B1 "inet $network_gateway" | head -1 | cut -d: -f1)
```

Comment: Here's the code that uses the `br-` prefix. https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/blob/b3507428be5b458cb0e2b4086b13531fb0706e46/drivers/bridge/bridge.go#L551

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jarek's answer, following docker compose can create & use `mybr0`

```yaml
version: "2.1"

services:
  network-only:
    image: tianon/true
    container_name: network-only
    networks:
      - mybr0

networks:
  mybr0:
    name: mybr0
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: mybr0
```

```bash
$sudo brctl show                      
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
docker0     8000.0242c5756f09   no      
mybr0       8000.0242798018bc   no
```